# Expanding label characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

Consider the following toy example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)

        toyLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello!")
        layout.addWidget(toyLabel)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Times", 16, QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        font.setStretch(150)
        toyLabel.setFont(font)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

How can I expand the letters of `toyLabel` without distorting it?

When using `setStretch()` as above the result is a mess:

[image]

I have also tried to expand the letters using a `font-stretch` property in a stylesheet but this is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this can be set directly in the `font` stylesheet property:

```
QLabel {
    font: 12px Times Expanded;
}
```